# Change image color with tapGesture on different viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to get the UIImageView `wCircle` to change to red when the UIImageView on a different viewController `rDot` is tapped. The problem is, when I tap `rDot` I get the error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code = EXC_I386_INVOP subcode = 0x0)` I made `wCircle` a global variable so it could be reached in the other viewController.

First viewController

```
weak var wCircle: UIImageView!

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var wCircle: UIImageView!
}
```

Second viewController

```
class ProgressViewController: UIViewController {   
    @IBOutlet weak var rDot: UIImageView!                   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()               
        rDot.isUserInteractionEnabled = true            
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rdotimageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))            
        rDot.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)          
    }    

    func rdotimageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        wCircle.image = wCircle.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate) //error on this line
        wCircle.tintColor = UIColor.red     
    }
}
```

Comment: I did my best to edit your code markdown - it wasn't making much sense. (Correct where needed. Thanks!) After the edit, it looks like some code is missing - maybe not needed, hard to say. How is the first controller instantiating the second? Is `rdotimageTapped` actually working? (Have you set a breakpoint to definitively answer that?) There may be other possibilities, but those are the first two that jump out at me.

Comment: @dfd thank you for that edit. I believe that is all the code needed for the question. `rdotimageTapped` is working. I am not too sure what you mean by the viewController instantiating the second.

Comment: @Tabj declaring global variable outside class is not a good idea.Therefor, encapsulate your global variables into their own class

Answer (score 0):

you code is not organized and indicate nothing Any way

change this line of code

replace  `weak var wCircle: UIImageView!`

with

```
weak var wCircle = UIImageView()
```

and this

```
func rdotimageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    wCircle?.image = whiteDot.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate) //error on this line
    wCircle?.tintColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Comment: with this code when I tap on `rDot` nothing happens. The tapGesture doesn't work.

Comment: it works but where is WCircle image Is it connected to IBoutlet or what?

Comment: I have it connected to IBoutlet in the first viewController.

Comment: your way in programming is Wrong , just share what you need to do

Comment: I did share what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

wCircle is weak variable and it is optional value.So when you are calling it from other class it can't be optional. Also make it strong variable